# Call JQuery plugin through Link function of Directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I dont know what exactly happend to this belove code

Template:

```
<article class="thumb" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <a href="{{product.largeImg}}" class="image" ><img ng-src=" {{product.smallImg}}" alt="" /></a>
    <h2>{{product.index}}. {{product.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{product.desc}}</p>
</article>
```

Directive

```
 mainApp.directive('contentdir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.store = {};
                $http.get('/getTemplate').success(function (data) {
                    $scope.store.products = data;
                });
            }],
        link: function ($scope, $element, attr) {
        setTimeout(function () {$('#main').poptrox({
                    baseZIndex: 20000,
                    /*options of poptrox*/
                });
            }, 10);
        }
    };
});
```

html

```
    <div id="main">
            <contentDir></contentDir>
    </div>
```

If i remove setTimeout in link function, code not working. Can explain to me what AngularJs work with this code. Thank you so much.

Comment: The code in setTimeout doesnt use $element or doesnt have anything to do with the directive. Why is it inside link function?

Comment: Template effect using jquery plugin and I try using it in Angularjs.

Comment: I think what Muthukannan is asking is why is your directive acting upon an element outside it, this does not reflect what directives are for. Shouldn't you remove the `#main` div and perhaps do this: `$element.poptrox()` inside the directive?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$timeout` provider instead of `setTimeout`, see: http://www.codelord.net/2015/10/14/angular-nitpicking-differences-between-timeout-and-settimeout/

TL;DR;

Angular won't "know" what happened inside `setTimeout`, if you use `$setTimeout`, that callback will be called inside Angular's digest cycle.

EDIT: I missread your question.

Either way you should use `$timeout`, the reason you need `$timeout` is because you need angular to create a separate digest cycle, if you leave the code to run synchronously, it won't work as Angular won't be aware of that change. Usually you'll find this:

```
$timeout(function(){
  // do something I want angular to be aware of. i.e.: a jQuery plugin
}, 0);
```

Comment: He says if he removes setTimeout, code doesnt work, not otherwise.

Comment: Tks for reply, when i setDelay = 0 in timeout, code still not working, but change delay to 20 or 50ms, it work. May be I guess issue involve render in browser or something else.